# My Custom Title with listview is not showing proper height and format

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, custom-titlebar

I want to give a custom title above my `listView`. After reading some `threads` here I made the code as follows, but the title bar size is becoming very small, i want to make it a little bigger. Also while `scrolling down` the list a big gap is created between the `listview` top and title bar. How can I avoid this? Can anybody help me?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.citylisttitle);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I did it.
First, in the manifest set your activity to have no title.

```
<activity android:name="Detail"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"/>
```

Then add your custom title bar at the top of the layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/detail_titleBar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/title_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/detail_account" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/detail_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/detail_titleBar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/detail_iconbar"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/detail_iconbar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    ....
```

Comment: This is a nice simple solution